# Why default value for column doesn't work with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using **django** to create database tables,model code like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=32,primary_key=True)
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,default='M')
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=40,default="")
```

but default value doesn't work.when I show table description,shows that:
[image]

why this code doesn't work and how can solve this problem?

Comment: When you save an object, does it take the default value?

Comment: How do you know its not working? Did you try adding a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django doesn't add default values into the schema, instead it adds the default value if need-be when a User object is created.

Comment: Really?why not update schema also?If we want to copy the database file to others for different application,should we add these default values in code?

Comment: Possibly due to inconsistencies between DBMS provides. Not entirely sure. But if you do plan to use the database in a non-django application, then you can always manually set the default in your schema. In MySQL it would be `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER column_name SET DEFAULT 'something'`